# How to find element by its class Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to click Log In button on Facebook Page. I'm trying to locate the button by class_name, but it returns an error.
html:
[image]

python:

```py
submit   = browser.find_element_by_class_name("a8c37x1j ni8dbmo4 stjgntxs l9j0dhe7 ltmttdrg g0qnabr5").text("Log In")
```

Comment: "...but it returns an error" - what error? Please include the full traceback as part of your question.

Comment: Try `submit = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("span.a8c37x1j.ni8dbmo4.stjgntxs.l9j0dhe7.ltmttdrg.g0qnabr5")`.

Comment: Oh sorry. ```Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".a8c37x1j ni8dbmo4 stjgntxs l9j0dhe7 ltmttdrg g0qnabr5"}```

Comment: See my comment. When searching by multiple classes, I find it more reliable by usng a CSS selector.

Comment: ```15340:19040:0205/220104.923:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(211)] [22:01:04.924] Bluetooth: bluetooth_adapter_winrt.cc:1072 Getting Default Adapter failed.``` What is it? And why selenium needs a Bluetooth Adapter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The space in the class name is like a seperator for the classes in css, what means that you look for many classes at once, so it wont work. Try it like this:

```
submit   = browser.find_element_by_class_name("a8c37x1j")
```

And when you want to click the button later on, you have to remove .text, because it just gives you the text of the button, but not the element. In order to click, just do this:

```
submit.click()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can chain it with css selectors.

**Example**

```
from selenium import webdriver

html = '''<span class="a8c37x1j ni8dbmo4 stjgntxs l9j0dhe7 ltmttdrg g0qnabr5">Log In</span>'''

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Program Files\ChromeDriver\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get("data:text/html;charset=utf-8,{0}".format(html))

driver.find_element_by_css_selector("span.a8c37x1j.ni8dbmo4.stjgntxs.l9j0dhe7.ltmttdrg.g0qnabr5")
```